# Python3.7 pip install requirement_string parsing error

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7, setup.py, egg

I am very new to python coding. I am trying is to use an existing custom package in my python script.

So I want to use a python package with one of my python script. 
To use the existing package (or `*.egg`) file I have followed following commands:

1. Build a python egg distribution from the root directory of my lib by executing following command: `python3 setup.py bdist_egg`
2. In my python script directory tried to execute following command into install the `.egg` created in the above step: `python3.7 -m pip install <path>/<to>/dist/<my_custom_lib>-0.14.0-py3.7.egg`

This gave me following error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 98, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1955, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3814, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd, found '/'  (at char 15), (line:1, col:16)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 358, in parse_req_from_line
    req = Requirement(req_as_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 102, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc : e.loc + 8], e.msg
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at "'/dist/me'": Expected stringEnd

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 302, in run
    check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 323, in get_requirements
    use_pep517=options.use_pep517,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 396, in install_req_from_line
    parts = parse_req_from_line(name, line_source)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 362, in parse_req_from_line
    add_msg += deduce_helpful_msg(req_as_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 169, in deduce_helpful_msg
    next(parse_requirements(fp.read()))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 12: invalid continuation byte
```

Not able to figure out what this any why this is happening. If this is due to the `setup.py` file content in the main lib, this is the content of it:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_custom_lib',
    version='0.14.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    url='https://www.my_custom_lib.com/qa/my_custom_lib',
    license='my_custom_lib Networks',
    author='my_custom_lib',
    author_email='my_custom_lib@my_custom_lib.com',
    description='Simulator library for the my_custom_lib Platform',
    long_description='''
        This Python module provides functionality to simulate an STB client
    using various protocol implementations, to test the
        my_custom_lib platform''',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Intended Audience :: Telecom',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
    ],
    install_requires=[
        'protocols',
        'numpy',
        'requests',
        'pycrypto',
        'psutil'
    ],
)
```

Not sure whats causing the issue, or what I am doing wrong here. Thanks for all your inputs and comments on this.

Comment: Have you ever publish any package to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/)?

Comment: @Carson No! Is it necessary to publish a package to use it via install command? Can't I use it from local path?

Comment: Posting to PyPI is not a necessary action, you can choose to share your script and install it on your computer, no problems!

Comment: I ask that question is to determine how I can help you. If you answer yes, then I think my answer is probably not suitable for you.

Comment: If you want to install your script on your computer, you only need to ``cd`` to the path of setup.py, and then ``pip install .`` and then it installs successfully.
Does it work for you?

Comment: If you can provide a complete file that can be downloaded, I believe the problem will be solved soon.
(you can remove the code of core, just make sure it can run only.)

Comment: The place where I have to install this script to use it, I don't have a `setup.py` file there. From your second last command thats what I am understanding, we have to have a `setup.py` if need to install the script. The `setup.py` file content I shared in the question is the file at the original repo.

Comment: ``protocols`` and ``pycrypto`` is necessary for you? (I can run with ``bdist_wheel`` ( not ``bdist_egg`` )  if I remove them)